# What is the use of base keyword however the Parent class constructor will be called by default.?

Tags: c#

I am aware that the base keyword is used to call the base class members if the members are overridden or hidden in derived classes. And I am clear that If we need to pass some parameters to the base class constructor by chaining in the constructor.

In the below example. I did not used the base keyword but its getting called. so what is the point?

```
class Person
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public static string Company { get; set; }

    static Person()
    {
        Company = "Company";
    }

    public Person()

    {
        Id = 0;
        Name = "Name";
    }

    public Person(long id)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = this.Name;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Id:{0}\tName:{1}\tCompany:{2}", Id, Name,Company);
    }
}

class Employee : Person
{
    public long EmpId { get; set; }
    public Employee()
    {

    }
}

class Manager : Employee
{
    public string WorkingWith { get; set; }

    public Manager()
    {

    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Manager manager = new Manager();

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

Is it an extra option to call the parameterized constructors from the derived class?

Comment: I don't know what answer you're looking for. Yes, it could have been used to choose *which* base class constructor to call, if the default one wasn't the one you wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly why you use `base` in your derived class constructor: to call parameterized constructor in base class:

```
: base(10, "test")
```

You can call parameterless base class constructor by `: base()`, but as you already said, it's pointless, because it will be called anyway.

Comment: Thanks to clarify me.

Comment: That leads to a new discussion wether it is good or bad style to call `base()` if it is implicitly called anyway.